# Academic figure components to create an Architecture design

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to make a figure that describes the the system architecture, but I am not able to make a figure that looks clean and professional like this  one:
[image: Architecture Design]

My Question: is there a piece of software that draws the components of the figure with same style (Computers, Hacker icons, and rectangles)?

I tried to make something that looks like this one using Adobe Illustrator, but I didn't find the appropriate icon set to have a clean figure.

Please can you help me to make clean figures like the one in the example.
Thanks,

Comment: Related: [Examples of well designed software architecture diagrams](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15788/examples-of-well-designed-software-architecture-diagrams)

Comment: and [Tools for Drawing Isometric Software Architectures](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11057/tools-for-drawing-isometric-software-architectures)

Comment: You can buy/download icons that fit your need from various sources yu dont need to draw them yourself

Answer (score 1):

- [Network Notepad](https://www.networknotepad.com/download.html) is a free 2D network diagram editor for Windows. The Network Notepad website also has a collection of more than 100 open source network object icons to use with Network Notepad which can be downloaded separately.
- [MaSSHandra](https://www.masshandra.com/) is a free cross platform (Windows/OS X/Linux) 3D network diagram editor. MaSSHandra can also make 2D network diagrams, datacenter diagrams, office diagrams and flowcharts. It can autodiscover networks and manually discover devices and their network connections. This is a convenient feature, but the 3D diagrams look blocky like Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

MS Office Visio is made for this.

https://products.office.com/en-us/visio/flowchart-software