# What technologies should I learn in order to design low-poly art for the web?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

What is the following type of art called and what technologies does one need to learn in order to produce this style of art? The best word I can think of to describe the art is low-poly but I have a suspicion this term isn't accurate.

[image]

The above image was obtained from this link: https://vueschool.io/

Other examples of this type of art can be found here: https://www.manypixels.co/?fbclid=IwAR0vTOD5im1dMec-4li8zENUx4DUv_fAkjnvpO8QFF4Ds5FimhpbLqoQal4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Isometric Flat

The name of this type of illustration is **Isometric Flat**. There are many results in Google as "isometric gradient", "isometric illustration" or "isometric flat".

About the best reproduction techniques you will find many answers if you type "isometric" in the search field of this site. There's also an in-depth analysis in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4938/120647).