# How to achieve this perceived 3D effect

Tags: text, logo, 3d

How do you achieve this effect, I tried the 3D effect but I wasn't able to get the same results with it.

I also tried the pen tool but again wasn't successful at it.

I am using Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: It's simply drawn. An [isometric grid](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/how-to-draw-isometric-vectors) may have been utilized, but that's not necessarily mandatory.

Comment: @Scott Thank you, that link helped a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice how all lines are either vertical or rotated 45°. This image follow a regular square grid, so it's easy to construct manually.

[image]

- Enter *Edit > Preferences > Guides & Grid* to set up the grid as you prefer. (Here I'm in a print document and have set *Grid > Gridline every* to *10 mm*.)
- Make sure the grid is visible with *View > Show Grid*.
- Make sure everything snaps to the grid by turning on *View > Snap to Grid*.
- Select a black stroke and no fill.
- Select a proper stroke width and make sure the caps are set to *Round Cap* so the ends of all lines fit neatly together.
- Select the *Line Segment Tool* and simple draw the shape line by line. (For each line I draw, I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click the artboard to deselect the last line.)

(By the way, notice how this object isn't fully closed and thereby isn't really a well-defined 3D object, but has a bit of optical illusion to it.)

Comment: You should disable shape widgets then you dont need to do the unselect dance. Just drag and drag

Comment: @joojaa, oh you don't like my moves? Disabling *corner widgets* doesn't seem to do any difference, but disabling *bounding box* does work. Thanks.

Comment: not corner widgets shape widgets